# Reduce boot time between grub menu and login screen

Tags: boot-time

I use Ubuntu 14.04 LTS version which used to boot fast at beginning but not i loads very slow. I searched for this but can't find suitable answers.

so i want to reduce my boot time which is now around 1min 12sec (boot chart) overall but i noticed its taking a longtime after grub menu and before login screen. A Blank screen appears after grub waiting... then login screen appears.

I want to know a way to reduce that blank screen time(or if possible remove) and get login screen as fast as possible.

I already removed several of my startup applications. Getting desktop after log-in is fast. I don't want to remove unity and install light desktop envinorments like Xfce and Lxde.

Thanks in advance

Edit: present i am using e4rat but that too did not save any time. I uninstalled ureadahead ubuntu-minimal packages to install e4rat.

My recent boot-chart image

[image]

I use a HDD hard disk(I don't want to buy a SSD)

My system configuration HP Pavilion dv6 3127tx, 3GB ram. I3 processor, 320GB sata harddisk, 1GB ATI Mobility radeon hd Graphic card and intel graphics, total boot time 50sec to 1min(above, it changes at every boot).

Comment: Buy one of this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Solid-state_drive

Comment: Better to look at dmesg using log file viewer or gksudo gedit /var/log/dmesg. Each entry is timestamped and long times may indicate an issue for further research. Also errors or warnings. Or repeated tries at loading a driver and failure or even success, but why multiple trys needs research. Do not post entire dmesg as it is long, but perhaps those with issues above.

Answer (score 4):

Although [e4rat](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/e4rat) documentation says "Users of SSD drives do not benefit because there are no moving parts and thus (almost) no disk latency" I'll bet you are using HDD not SSD, aren't you? Because the time you provided is even more than one (1) minute, I assume it is HDD.

You asked a enough wide question which touches different approaches and methods of optimization. One of them is using SSD and ut brings performance and boot time which you desire.

Comment: HDD with I5-3230 laptop 6Gb ram, 39 secs.  Hardware may indeed be your issue.  Please post your hardware config.